# TransformedValue outputs from PMML - implementation-specific differences

Tags: pmml

I have some derived fields in my PMML model which I want to expose as output fields. And.... I can get that to work in both Augustus and JPMML (via OpenScoring), but I seem to have to do it slightly differently. I wonder if anyone has any views on which of them is doing it *correctly*? The PMML spec doesn't seem to be 100% clear on this.

For JPMML, I can do it by just referring to the derived fields I want, and I must avoid including them as "predicted" in the MiningSchema.

```
<MiningSchema>
    <MiningField name="foo_input" usageType="active"/>
</MiningSchema>
<Output>
    <OutputField name="foo_output" dataType="integer" feature="transformedValue" optype="continuous">
        <FieldRef field="foo_derived"/>
    </OutputField>
</Output>
```

But that doesn't work with Augustus. For that, I need to declare these outputs as "predicted" fields in the MiningSchema.

```
<MiningSchema>
    <MiningField name="foo_input" usageType="active"/>
    <MiningField name="foo_output" usageType="predicted"/>
</MiningSchema>
<Output>
    <OutputField name="foo_output" dataType="integer" feature="transformedValue" optype="continuous">
        <FieldRef field="foo_derived"/>
    </OutputField>
</Output>
```

So I'm having to generate different PMML depending on what I expect the target scoring environment to be... which doesn't sound good. But which one is doing it right? Or is there an alternative way of expressing it that will be more portable?

In all of those fragments above, *foo_derived* is just a derived field based on the *foo_input* input value. Doesn't seem to make any difference whether it's a local transformation or a global one.

```
<DerivedField name="foo_derived" dataType="integer" optype="continuous">
    <Apply function="+"> <!-- example definition, actual one is a bit more complicated -->
        <FieldRef field="foo_input"/>
        <Constant dataType="integer">1</Constant>
    </Apply>
</DerivedField>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`MiningSchema` element](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-2-1/MiningSchema.html) declares which field values must be "imported" for scoring the model element. Additionally, it may declare the name of the sole target field if the model element represents a supervised learning model:

> `target`: field that was used a training target for supervised models.

Augustus appears to assume that the `MiningSchema` element must also declare which field values are "exported". However, this assumption is not supported by the PMML specification in any way. The `OutputField` element is a standalone entity and its existence does not need to be "confirmed" by any other element.

So, you should export your models with JPMML in mind. If you need to make them scorable on Augustus also, then you may consider temporarily rearranging them using JPMML's Visitor API.

Comment: Thanks. That all makes sense. I'm encountering other issues with Augustus anyway, so JPMML/OpenScoring sounds a better bet (and hopefully ADAPA et al will be behaving like JPMML does). Things like recursive function definitions, nullable booleans, etc.